# How can I prevent hashing of session IDs in typo3?

Tags: php, typo3

I work with Typo3 and the actual session ID from the cookie is hashed into the database. How can I turn off the hashing? I am using Typo3 version 11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't turn that off by any configuration. Of course you could change the code directly but that is not something this should be done.

May I ask why you need to disable that?

---

Some additional background taken from Oliver Hader at https://talk.typo3.org/t/disable-hashing-of-ses-id-possible/4617

The change you referring to was part of a security fix, which is described at [TYPO3-CORE-SA-2020-011](https://typo3.org/security/advisory/typo3-core-sa-2020-011): Cleartext storage of session identifier.
Besides that, I also demonstrated a potential attack technically during the TYPO3 Online Days 2021, which can be watched again on YouTube at [TYPO3 Online Days 2021 - #T3OD21 - Day 2 - June 30, 2021 - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HT_vGwXEEbs&t=10940s)

The hashing implementation for the database component is show at [[SECURITY] Protect persisted session IDs from being used directly · TYPO3/typo3@dc26a4a](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/commit/dc26a4ac1a7a8f78f3556dbcd2140d51b046d593#diff-376bee04c40207572de37140e4abf2343b7ee81f19c6891fe60ea52db9eb40fdR76-R82)

For security reasons (as explained in the resources above), it is not possible to deactivate hashing (via HMAC) of the persisted identifier.

Comment: Do you know where I get the salt und key to hash the cookie session?

Comment: I added the information to my original response, the last link is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks, but is there any similar solution for felogin?

Comment: what do you mean? ext:felogin just does some templating and redirecting but doesn't take care of the actual login